# How do I conditionally set status code in Project Reactor Netty HTTP Server?

Tags: netty, project-reactor, reactor-netty

I suspect I'm missing something really obvious here, but I can't work out how to achieve a very simple use case with the HttpServer in reactor-netty.

Essentially, I want to implement the ability to respond with `200 OK` when a response object is not null, and `404 Not Found` when a response object is null.

I'm using Kotlin, and adding an extension function to HttpServerResponse to map an object to JSON:

```
fun <T> HttpServerResponse.sendObjectAsJson(obj: Mono<T?>, mapper: (T) -> JsonObject): NettyOutbound {
    val jsonString = obj.map { mapper(it!!) }.map { it.toString() }
    return this
       .status(OK)
       .header(CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json")
       .sendString(jsonString)
    }
}
```

This code currently breaks if the source object is null (due to use of `it!!`). What I actually want to achieve is switch the response status code and not send any string content if the source object is null. But, I just can't work out how to switch the behaviour based on the content of `Mono<T?>`.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I don't use Kotlin, but as a guess at translation, could you switch the first line in the function to something like `val jsonString = obj.map { it?.toString() }`, then use `.status(if (jsonString == null) OK else OTHER_STATUS_CODE)` for the status code and `.sendString(jsonString ?: "")` for the response body?

Comment: Thanks for your idea. The issue - which I did not articulate well - is that you can't do your second line of code because jsonString would be a Mono<String?> and not just a String? This is the root of my confusion and why there does not seem to be an obvious approach

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve similar problem with following code

```java
Mono<String> valueMono = Mono.from(...).doOnSuccess(s -> {
  if (s == null) {
    response.status(HttpResponseStatus.NOT_FOUND);
  }
});
return response.sendString(valueMono);
```